# Geometrical/Combinatorial interpretation of $ \pi = \frac{27}{4 \sqrt 3} \sum_2^∞ \frac{1}{C(k)} $

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

I found this question on [here](https://ru-math.livejournal.com/399814.html), but no real answer was given. Is there a geometrical or combinatorial interpretation of this result?

$ \pi = \frac{27}{4 \sqrt 3} \sum_2^∞ \frac{1}{C(k)} $

Where $ C(k) $ are the Catalan numbers.
This result can be derived from [here](https://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/about/sum-of-reciprocals/) and this is the [oeis reference](https://oeis.org/A121839)

Comment: Can you translate the essential part from your first link from Russian into English, and from Spanish to English from the second link?

Comment: @DietrichBurde essentially in the first link the author asks the same question, while in the second a generating function is used to find the identity, you can find all the references in the oeis link

Comment: If it is all included in the OEIS link, it makes no sense to include foreign language links. I thought that the "answer given there" in Russian is actually helping. Why is this not the case ("not a real answer")?

Comment: @DietrichBurde well I included the Spanish link too because it explicitly derive the generating function. I tried translated the comments in the Russian link but found no answer to the question

Comment: "**What is** the geometrical or ..." $\to$ "**Is there** a geometrical or ... "

Comment: See the solution to Problem 11765 in *The American Mathematical Monthly* **123** (4) (April 2016), 405–406 for some discussion of reciprocal Catalan sums $\sum x^n/C_n$. At the time of writing you can access it as the last two pages of https://lupucezar.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/amm-problem-section-april-2016.pdf